# does Jboss 7.1 web server is Tomcat ? if so does it have separate configuration files than the jboss standalone.xml file?

Tags: tomcat, jboss7.x

does Jboss 7.1 web server is Tomcat ? if so does it have separate configuration files than the jboss standalone.xml file ?
I know in old version of joss this was the situation , but how is it in Jboss 7 ?
what is the business relation between Apache and Red Hat ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's core is still the catalina.jar repackaged to jbossweb.jar - see jboss.as.web module. But stuff you saw in web.xml in jboss-web.deployer is  configured programmatically (see [org.jboss.as.web.SharedWebMetaDataBuilder](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org.jboss.as/jboss-as-web/7.1.1.Final/org/jboss/as/web/SharedWebMetaDataBuilder.java) and [org.jboss.as.web.WebSubsystemAdd](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org.jboss.as/jboss-as-web/7.1.1.Final/org/jboss/as/web/WebSubsystemAdd.java))